# why do i get not supported exception with IQueryable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i've my JsonResult function  as follow 
   public JsonResult IsLive(string username)
   {

```
User  usr = Database.Session.Query<User>().FirstOrDefault(u=>u.username == 
username.ToString());

if (usr != null)
{
usr.LastHeartBeat = DateTime.Now;
Database.Session.SaveOrUpdate(usr);

}
List<string> onlineUsersList =Database.Session.Query<User>().Where(u => 
IsActive(u.LastHeartBeat)== true).Select(u => u.username).ToList(); 

return Json(onlineUsersList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

but i get this exception when i try to access

```
Boolean IsActive(System.DateTime)
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information 
about 
the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Boolean 
IsActive(System.DateTime)

Source Error: 


Line 150:                //sentStatus = "saved";
Line 151:            }
Line 152:            List<string> onlineUsersList 
=Database.Session.Query<User>().Where(u => 
IsActive(u.LastHeartBeat)).Select(u => u.username).ToList(); 
Line 153:           // string sentStatus = username;
Line 154:            return Json(onlineUsersList, 
JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Source File:  2013\Projects\EtlGui\Controllers\UsersController.cs    Line: 
152
```

and this is my another function that refernced to where clause

```
bool IsActive(DateTime heartBeatTime)
{
 string ActiveOrInactive = "Active";
try
{
TimeSpan span = (TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - heartBeatTime);
if (span.TotalSeconds >= 120)
{
 return false;
 }
return true;
}
catch (Exception)
{
return false;
}
}
```

from these what am i doing wrong because i've tried to trace it the whole day but no result so far!

Comment: Where is the IQueryable in the error messages?  And from what API is Database.Session.Query<User>() ?

Comment: My guess is that you're trying to pass the `IsActive` method into something like Entity Framework and it has no idea what to do with it.

Comment: Database.Session.Query<User>() is definately the IQueryable

Comment: `Where(u => 
IsActive(u.LastHeartBeat))` or `Where(u => 
IsActive(u.LastHeartBeat) == true)` (your question includes both versions) makes no sense (in either case). You can't restrict rows by an external field. Even if EF knew what to do with it, it would turn into something like `true = false` or `true = true` Did you mean something like `Where(u => u.SomeField ==
IsActive(u.LastHeartBeat)`? It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. You perhaps need to select the u.LastHeartBeat and _then_ pass it to the IsActive method?

Comment: Use the proper tags to get help, like[C#] , [Entity-framework] etc.

Comment: thanks  alot i finally cast to IEnumerable and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you've got is that `IsActive()` cannot be converted to SQL and it will need to be filtered after returning the results back to the app.

```
List<string> onlineUsersList =Database.Session.Query<User>().Where(u => 
    IsActive(u.LastHeartBeat)== true).Select(u => u.username).ToList();
```

To use `IsActive` you'll have to retrieve all from the database then filter

```
var sessions = Database.Session.ToList();
List<string> onlineUsersList = sessions.Where(u => 
    IsActive(u.LastHeartBeat)== true).Select(u => u.username).ToList();
```

Comment: Yep, anything that's not `IQueryable<>` will work. Feel free to accept this answer if it provides a solution to your question